# Is it possible to have a private module named `lib` if I specify a separate lib target in Cargo.toml?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have a **binary** application I'm developing in Rust with a `lib` directory of helpers, and I want to know how to export helper functions for integration testing—e.g.

```
src
|- data_access_layer.rs
|- main.rs
|- lib
   |- util.rs
```

When I tried to export data_access_layer helpers for integration testing I added a `[lib]` configuration to my Cargo.toml pointing at `test_lib.rs`

```rust
// test_lib.rs

pub mod data_access_layer;
```

with a file structure that now looks like this:

```
src
|- data_access_layer.rs
|- main.rs
|- lib
   |- util.rs
|- test_lib.rs
```

...but when I try to run (or test) my application now, I get errors like **"could not find `lib` in the crate root"**

Here's my Cargo.toml file.

```ini
[package]
name = "api-service"
version = "0.11.14"
edition = "2018"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
diesel = { version = "2", features = ["mysql", "extras", "chrono", "r2d2"] }

[dev-dependencies]
pretty_assertions = "1.2.1"


[lib]
name = "test_lib"
path = "src/test_lib.rs"
```

What would you advise in this situation? Is it just a bad idea to store my own helpers under a collision file name like this? I would expect my TOML config to free up the word `lib` for use...

Answer (score 1):

I assume you still want to use stuff in `src/lib/utils.rs` in wich case you still need to create either `src/lib.rs` or `src/lib/mod.rs` with the following content:

```rust
// either src/lib.rs or src/lib/mod.rs
pub mod utils;
```

That being said it's still a bad idea to use the name `lib` for some internal module and add a custom `[lib]` section cause it will confuse other people looking at the code, thus it should only be done with a good reason to do so.

Comment: If I have a `lib/mod.rs` etc... can I automatically write integration tests against that? It seemed like I wasn't able to because the `main.rs` forces Cargo to assume it's a binary

Comment: Integration tests would be against the `[lib]` defined in `Cargo.toml` so `test_lib.rs` in your case. If you want to include `lib/mod.rs` in the integration tests you have to mention it in the module hierarchy of that file.

Comment: Would this work better if I just wrote integration tests against my existing `lib` directory and added this to my Cargo.toml file? 

```[lib]
name = "lib"
path = "src/lib/mod.rs"
```

Comment: Probably, though I would not name it "lib" but just go with the default of `crate_name`, the defaults are there for a reason and messing with them will make it significantly harder to work with your code for others.

Comment: Ah, interesting. Got it